# Действительно - часть речи

Tags: наречия, части-речи, частица, вопрос

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой частью речи будет являться слово "действительно" в данном предложении? А также какой вопрос задаем (если задаем)

- Действительно ли первый час после пробуждения способен изменить нашу жизнь до неузнаваемости?

Comment: Если и последний час не может изменить это слово, то часть речи называется...